# Analyzing CPU usage of an iOS application

Tags: iphone, debugging, instruments, cpu-usage

I'm working on an application that constructs springboard like interface (like iPhone's home screen). I have multiple pages, and each page contains many subviews. Each subview is able to detect touch and hold event. Once a touch and hold event is recognized, all the subviews start to wobble.

One of the problems that i'm facing is that the CPU usage shoots to 99%, when the subviews are in wobble state, and i change the page.

Instruments has a tool by the name of "CPU Sampler". I'm unable to find good set of documentation for this tool. I don't know how to read the output generated by this tool. Can anyone give me a small tutorial or guidelines? Can i check which piece of code is responsible for the CPU activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to WWDC 2010 Session Videos, and pick Session 135 - Advanced Performance Optimization on iPhone OS. It explains quite a lot about the Core Animations instrument.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the CPU Sampler but i think you can find something useful in this link related to your question.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1229351

Comment: Thanks, but these articles doesn't provide any information that is not covered by the Apple's official documentation.